# Connect httpServer to client through a specific socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, httpserver

I have made an httpServer which is connected with the client with Socket client = socket.accept(). Is there a command in order to choose which port I want to use to send messages to the client??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have a fixed outbound port on the client? You can't do that.

See [How is source port for HTTP determined? Is there ever collision in NAT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708011/how-is-source-port-for-http-determined-is-there-ever-collision-in-nat)

Why do you want to do that?

An httpServer only responds on client requests. It cannot send data to the client without a request from the client. If you want to have bi-directional communication, you need websockets.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I didn't understand correctly what the project I have to do asked for

Answer (score 0):

Your server will use the port that you selected when you create your `ServerSocket socket = ServerSocket(your port)`